# Lie back vs. lean back vs. recline

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I am a little confused as to what the differences in meaning and/or in usage between these three word choices are (all in their intransitive forms).

Merriam-webster defines them as follows:

> **Lie back**: to lean backward against a support
>
> **Lean**: to incline, deviate, or bend from a vertical position (it doesn't have an entry for *lean back*)
>
> **Recline**: to lean or incline backwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To lean {on|against}* X means to rely on X to keep you upright - generally, while you are standing or sitting outside of a chair.

*To lie back* would apply if you are about 45 degrees or less in orientation, and generally means your back is going to be relying on something else for support.  A doctor may ask you to lie back on an examination chair, which flattens out where you are then lying down.

*Recline* means to "lie back" in a sitting position, and can strongly suggest you are on a sofa or other seat with a back, that is not flat enough for you to be considered "lying" when on it.

Comment: How about lean back? Does it always imply reclining on something other than a chair?

Comment: When you lean, you can lean forward, to the left, or any arbitrary direction.  So that's just specifying the direction you are leaning.  Another way to put this: "Lie" means you are more or less flat on a surface, "recline" means you are sitting, and "lean" is what you'd use if whether you are sitting, standing, or lying doesn't matter.